# Migrations not running on server in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration, laravel-migrations

So I have a custom package which I am using in my project which has a lot of migrations. The package contains a lot of migrations and seeds.

In the service provider of the package, I load the migrations like so:

```
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/database/migrations/');
```

When I run `php artisan migrate:refresh` locally, it works like a charm and the migrations are run and the tables are installed in the DB. But when I do the same on my server, it says nothing to migrate which is confusing since the same config works in my homestead env and not my production env.

Has anyone else faced a similar problem or has any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: I didn't find anything about migrations in Laravel official documentation about packages, I think you should manual create command for adding migrations.

Comment: there could be 2 possibilities either migration files are missing or path is not correct, using    base_path() can help. Also if files are present and path is being proper a dirty trick could be deleting the respected entries in migration table and running the migrations again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the placement is different on your server, or that the command is executed from another place? `__DIR__` isn't too reliable in the best of situations.

Try abstracting your code by changing the line to this:

```
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(base_path() . '/database/migrations/');
```

`base_path()` and `app_path()` are handy functions when dealing with specific file locations inside your Laravel code :)

EDIT: Ow and another possibility: your migrations haven't been added to your git repository. Happens to me more often than I care to admit ;-)

Comment: I have tried a lot of combinations with path, including `realpath()` and `base_path()` methods, it does not work. In face I tried `dd()` on the `__DIR__` path and it comes out fine.

Comment: Mmmhh... What does your migrations table say? And did you verify that the migrations are in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git, check if the branch on the server is the same as the one on the development environment.

For example, you might be on the `master` branch on the server (by default) and you did all your development in the `development` branch. Because of this the migrations will only be visible in the `development` branch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be one of this.

```
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations/');
```

or

```
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/./database/migrations/');
```